# gmaps4rails is not displaying the map

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I don't know what I am missing.
I saw in another post that gmaps4rails gem includes some javascripts code dealing with json, and in the code rendered of my page it doesn't appears.
The container window for the map is blank, without any map inside.
I am running rails 3.2.8, ruby 1.9.3 and gmaps4rails 1.5.5.
Thanks in advance.

## Controller code

```
respond_to :json, :html

def mostrar_mapa_unidades
  @json = Unidade.all.to_gmaps4rails
  respond_with @json
end
```

## View code

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
<%= @json %>
```

## Model code

```
acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false
```

## application.html.erb code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SONep</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
<%= yield :scripts %>
</body>
</html>
```

## Rendered web page code (main parts)

```
<link href="/assets/gmaps4rails.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.bing.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.mapquest.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.openlayers.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div class="map_container"> 
  <div id="map" class="gmaps4rails_map"></div>
</div>

@json

[{&quot;lat&quot;:&quot;-23.701613&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;-46.547077&quot;},{&quot;lat&quot;:&quot;-23.704757&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;-46.545274&quot;},{&quot;lat&quot;:&quot;-23.7074712&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;-46.5419723&quot;}]
```

Comment: really weird, seems the necessary js isn't included in thanks to `yield :scripts`. Don't understand though. Any error somewhere?

Comment: No error. Thanks for your support. I will try to implement the requirement that I have using google maps API.

Comment: ok, can't tel much more given the info, sorry.

Comment: another people reported the error but I can't reproduce it. could you do a dummy app with the bug?